# Why do these two different use-package declarations (for the same package) have different effects?

Tags: key-bindings, eshell, use-package

What I want to accomplish is to add a keybinding `C-<backspace>` to the `eshell-mod-map` that calls `func`. That can be done like this,

```lisp
(use-package eshell
  :init
  (defun add-func-keybinding ()
    (define-key
      eshell-mode-map
      (kbd "C-<backspace>")
      (lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (func "arg"))))
  :hook
  (eshell-mode . add-func-keybinding))
```

Now `C-<backspace>` *only* calls `func` when inside an eshell buffer. I thought this should be equivalent to,

```lisp
(use-package eshell
  :after esh-mode
  :bind
  (:map eshell-mode-map
     ("C-<backspace>" . (lambda () (interactive) (func "arg")))))
```

However, this binds `C-<backspace>` to `func` everywhere, e. g., if I press `C-<backspace>` in the `*scratch*` buffer, that also calls `func`. This does not happen when the configuration is done as in the former `use-package` declaration, there the keybinding is kept only inside the eshell buffer.

However, I fail to see the difference between the two declarations. I would like to fix the latter so it has the same effect as the former, since the latter is a bit clearer and nicer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it that way.

```
(use-package esh-mode
  :bind (:map eshell-mode-map
              ("C-<backspace>" . my-eshell-mode-func))
  :config (defun my-eshell-mode-func ()
            (interactive)
            (func "arg")))
```

For two reasons:

- `eshell-mode-map` is provided by feature `esh-mode` (not `eshell`) [see end of this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/master/lisp/eshell/esh-mode.el)
- because it is [not a good idea to bind lambdas directly to keys](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-lisp-style-guide#functions). (I'm even not sure, if that works at all)

---

To answer your "why":
Because your first use-package form binds a define-key form to the hook `eshell-mode-hook`, which is sort of unrelated to feature eshell (because it belongs to feature esh-mode). But this hook triggers everytime, the feature esh-mode goes into action.
In your second use-package form this connection to feature esh-mode is missing (`:after esh-mode` results in something different).

*Edit:* Here is some fun: in old versions of file esh-mode.el `eshell-mode-map` gets fille as local variable, right in that moment, when `eshell-mode` was enabled by the user. With killing of the buffer `eshell-mode-map` went nil again. There is even a comment in source code:

> ;; FIXME: What the hell!?

That is probably the reason why your first use-package form uses a hook.
This setup of `eshell-mode-map` as a buffer local variable is still present in version 26.3 of Emacs. So binding your `define-key` to hook `eshell-mode-hook` is a valid option until you upgrade.
In more recent versions this has been fixed and my above solution should work.

---

Be aware, I cannot test this solution, because my emacs is way to old and does not has the line `(provide 'esh-mode)` in file esh-mode.el. And my OS does not map a `backspace` key to my physical keyboard.

Comment: Tested what you have with `func` replaced with `message`. Unfortunately, the keybinding was available in `*scratch*` mode.

Comment: This sounds like some sort of bug. Anyway, which emacs version are you using? There have been changes in file esh-mode.el. Read my answer again and check for the comment in your esh-mode.el.

Comment: I am using 26.3, could you tell me where to find the `esh-mode.el`?

Comment: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/tags  you can extract this source code to your harddisk and make it known to emacs with variable `source-directory` you can then easily look up source code of functions  and features.

Comment: this weird local variable of `eshell-mode-map` is still present in 26.3. so you need a `hook` to set up your key until you upgrade to a more recent version.

Comment: Does all source for Emacs not automatically come with the package from the repository? For example, when I do `C-h v org-mode-map`, I get a buffer with the first line being `org-mode-map is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.` There I can just go to the `org.el`.

Comment: This depends, on Debian for example, Emacs can be installed without its source code.